# displaying in forms data inserted into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created this table that part of it takes input from the user and save it in the database..

I'm trying to make the data put by the user in the  tags remain shown. Basically the input form becoming both input/output source. Any help on how to do so?

```
switch ($selected){
    case 'University':
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT employees.afnumber,employees.name,employees.actualpost,university.brevet FROM employees,university WHERE employees.status='Employed' AND employees.afnumber=university.afnumber ORDER BY employees.afnumber DESC LIMIT :start,:end");
        $stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $selectedtable  = "<form method='post' action=''>\n";
        $selectedtable .= "<table class='sortable'>\n<tr><th>Description</th><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>\n";
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $selectedtable .= "<tr><th>Brevet</th><td><input type='text' name='Brevet1' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>Baccalaureat/BT</th><td><input type='text' name='Baccalaureatbt' style=' padding: 10px; font-size:16px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>License/TS</th><td><input type='text' name='Licensets' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>M1</th><td><input type='text' name='M1' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>Master's Degree</th><td><input type='text' name='Mastersdegree' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>
                       <tr><th>PHD</th><td><input type='text' name='Phd' style=' padding: 10px; margin-top:1px; border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'></td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>";

    }
    $selectedtable .= "</table>\n"; 
    $selectedtable .= "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>\n";
    $selectedtable .= "</form>\n";

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   $brevet1 = $_POST['Brevet1'];
        $baccalaureatbt = $_POST['Baccalaureatbt'];
        $licensets = $_POST['Licensets'];
        $m1 = $_POST['M1'];
        $mastersdegree = $_POST['Mastersdegree'];
        $phd = $_POST['Phd'];


     $sql1="SELECT Brevet1,Baccalaureatbt,Licensets,M1,Mastersdegree,Phd FROM university";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
  {

  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  }
    if($rowcount==0)
     {
 $sql="INSERT INTO university(Brevet1,Baccalaureatbt,Licensets,M1,Mastersdegree,Phd) VALUES('$brevet1','$baccalaureatbt','$licensets','$m1','$mastersdegree','$phd')";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
     }
     else
     {
 $sql2 = "UPDATE university SET Brevet1 = '$brevet1' , Baccalaureatbt = '$baccalaureatbt', Licensets = '$licensets', M1 = '$m1', Mastersdegree = '$mastersdegree', Phd = '$phd'";
 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
     }

    }


    break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a value to each input like this :

`<input type='text' name='Brevet1' value="<?php echo $_POST['brevet_1']; ?>">`

With a ternary condition : 
`echo (!empty($_POST['brevet_1']) ? $_POST['brevet_1'] : '');`

**EDIT**

Fetch the data from database and set the value of input just like above

Comment: This is a solution if the form submits and the values are updated/inserted **before** the select statement.

Comment: So @dan look at my edit, and juste fetch the data from database to set input value

Comment: @dan give the bounty to this man, he worths fine ;) This answer is the same that I will write if there isn't another yet.If this not solve your problem, maybe you need to explain better or share more pieces of code.

Comment: @wilson is it possible to open a chat conv for a second

Comment: @dan yeah sure no problem

Comment: @wilson got to get that automatic chat conv open

Comment: any other way to open a chat conv than this?

Comment: I don't know if private conv here is possible

Comment: So with the comment we can ;)

Comment: @wilson anyway reguarding the ternary condition where to use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86695/discussion-between-dan-and-wilson).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've always done in these kind of situations. Suppose your page name is `mypage.php`. Now, you open mypage.php with an `id` (like `mypage.php?id=1`, and you can get the id as `$_GET['id']`). This `id` would be the `auto_increment` value of the table you need to insert / update.

Now, on `mypage.php`, write this code :-

```
    <form action="someEndFile.php" method="post">
        <?php echo $command; ?>
        <?php if($command == 1)
        {
$userData = fetch via $_GET['id'];
            ?>
            Your input Tags Here
            Submit Button Here
            <input type='text' name='somename' value='<?php echo $userdata->valueFromTheDatabase; ?>'>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <input type='text' name='somename'>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </form>
```

In the `if(data_exists)` block, check if any record in the table exists with the id `id` (which you received as $_GET['id']). If the record exists, it will go inside the `if` block and the `command value` would be `1`, that means `update`. 
If the ID didn't existed, it would go to `else` and the value would be `2`, which means `insert new`.

Now, in your form, echo `$command` and put all the fields. Here check the value of `$command` and echo the value inside the input tags accordingly.

Now on the `someEndFile.php` file, have a code like this :-

```
<?php
$command = isset($_POST['command']) ? $_POST['command'] : '';
switch($command)
{
    case 1:
    //update case
    write your update query here;
    break;
    case 2:
    //insert case
    write your insert query here;
    break;
}
?>
```

You can now execute your needed query. This is what I always do in these type of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example where the input form data is displayed when the form is submitted. As a bonus, it also shows some basic PHP form validation as well:

[w3schools Example of showing the form entry on the same page as entered](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_escapechar)

echo out the variables for the values entered on the page. You can place the echo statements as needed, within tags formatting as you like.

Example:
if your form contains:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
```

Then display the tag containing 'name' anywhere on the page like this:

```
<?php
//check if name has changed:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}
?>


<?php
//echo the new field entry
echo $name;
?>
```